# image_dataset_from_directory can't read png, jpeg file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

here is my code

colab goes well but vscode doesn't

```
image_dir = "ai/data/toonder_img"
batch_size = 32
image_size = (64, 64)

train_ds = image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory=image_dir,
    labels="inferred",
    color_mode='grayscale',
    class_names=['class'],
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    seed=1337
    )

class_names = train_ds.class_names
take = train_ds.take(1)

print(train_ds.element_spec)
print("class_names : ", class_names)
print("data_mode   : ", take)

for images in train_ds.take(10):
  print('images.shape: ', images.shape)
```

here is my error

```
Found 293 files belonging to 1 classes.
(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 64, 64, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))
class_names :  ['class']
data_mode   :  <_TakeDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 64, 64, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kite/Desktop/2023_2_Toonder2.0/ai/toonder_module/toonder_img_ai.py", line 42, in <module>
    for images in train_ds.take(10):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 809, in __next__
    return self._next_internal()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 772, in _next_internal
    ret = gen_dataset_ops.iterator_get_next(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py", line 3028, in iterator_get_next
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 5888, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__IteratorGetNext_output_types_2_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required.
         [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext] name:
```

what should I do? why I can't read png file?

Answer (score 0):

In your error message, the key part is **"Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required."** This means that the image files in your dataset might not be in one of the expected file formats and so the TensorFlow code is having trouble reading it.

You should try to:

- Ensure that all the images in your directory are in JPEG, PNG, GIF or BMP. Try checking the file extension or opening up a few images to verify they are not corrupted.
- Make sure you are using the most updated version of TensorFlow as sometimes bugs in the library can cause issues.
- Make sure your directory contains only image files. The image loading function might try to process non-image files as images, leading to errors.
- Since you are using grayscale images, make sure images are in grayscale format. If they are color images, you might need to convert them to grayscale as part of your preprocessing.